# I'm getting an unexpected end of file error with my script

Tags: linux, scripting

I'm having a bit of an issue with some code I'm writing for a Linux script.
Here's the code:

```
report_home_space ()
{
if [[ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]]; then
        cat << _eof_
                 <H2>Home Space Utilization (All Users)</H2>
                 <PRE>$(du -sh /home/*)</PRE>
               _eof_
else
        cat << _eof_
                 <H2>Home Space Utilization ($USER)</H2>
                 <PRE>$(du -sh $HOME)</PRE>
               _eof_
fi
return
}
```

There are other functions in the script but they all work correctly. The script is pulling the error around an end of file token somewhere in this snippet of code but I can't find it. I have the fi statement for the if statement and my end of file tokens all match up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

After going through some of the answers that were provided I was able to get rid of the initial unexpected eof error but the same error is happening again but in a different location in my script. (line 58 to be exact, the last line of the script). I'll provide the entire script so it can be examined.

```
#!/bin/bash


#Program is used to output sys info as a web page

TITLE="System Information Report for $HOSTNAME"
CURRENT_TIME=$(date +"%x %r %Z")
TIME_STAMP="Generated $CURRENT_TIME, by $USER"

report_uptime () 
{
cat <<- _eof_
           <H2>System uptime</H2>
           <PRE>$(uptime)</PRE>
       _eof_
return
}

report_disk_space ()
{
cat <<- _eof_
           <H2>Disk space utilization</H2>
           <PRE>$(df -h)</PRE>
       _eof_
return
}

report_home_space () {
 if [[ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]]; then
                cat <<- _eof_
                           <H2>Home Space Ultilization (All Users)</H2>
                           <PRE>$(du -sh /home/*)</PRE>
                           _eof_
        else
                cat <<- _eof_
                           <H2>Home Space Ultilization ($USER)</H2>
                           <PRE>$(du -sh $HOME)</PRE>
                           _eof_
        fi
        return
}


cat <<- _eof_
      <HTML>
           <HEAD>
                     <TITLE>$TITLE</TITLE>
           </HEAD>
           <BODY>
                       <H1>$TITLE</H1>
                       <P1>$TIME_STAMP</P1>
                       $(report_uptime)
                       $(report_disk_space)
                       $(report_home_space)
           </BODY>
      </HTML>
_eof_
```

I tried moving the EOFs to the beginning of the lines and the didn't do much. This script is in a command line book that I'm reading and I copied the script exactly and it's throwing the EOF errors. I'm guessing because the book might be outdated.

Once again thanks for all of the help.

Comment: Check your line endings, DOS-style `\r\n` confuses some shells.

Answer (score 2):

Your HEREDOC terminators are incrorect. They must be at the beginning of the line.

e.g.

```
cat << EOF
   foo bar
   EOF
^^^--these spaces matter
```

Because of those spaces, the terminator is seen as `[space][space][space]EOF`, and will never match `EOF` by itself.

Since your first EOF never terminates, the shell runs off the end of the script without ever seeing the `fi`, because the `fi` you have was actually treated as output, not a control sequence.

Comment: Yup, that or use [`<<-`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells) if these are tabs and not spaces.